# Disassembling a vintage coffee grinder

Tags: metalworking

I'm trying to disassemble a vintage coffee grinder, so I could clean it and put back together. It is probably made in the first half of last century, mostly or all manual work. There is a joint that holds the crank in place (zoomed on photo) and I do not know how it is built. Its rather soft metal so knocking it with hammer in wrong way will disfigure it. Can anyone guess what it is? Some kind of wedge, a screw or something else?

[image: Coffee grinder]

Comment: Have you applied a thin oil (or even a thing like WD40) on all possible screw/locking locations?

Comment: Yes, had it soaked with WD40 for couple of days before. I have a feeling the joint is some kind of rivet, hammered shut. I'll try to clean the whole thing with soda blaster, leaving the crank in place

Answer (score 1):

Try holding the blades stationary while turning the handle in the direction opposite of the direction it turns during grinding.  That will possible unscrew the blades section from the top, leaving you with three easily cleanable and re-assemble-able pieces.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite good suggestion, I fixed the handle with vices and tried to turn the shaft with pipe wrench - it did not budge. Perhaps I gave up just before applying enough torque but I'm sure any rusty thread would have yielded. Tried both directions too.